# Install Learning Locker on AWS EC2 and got error 404

Tags: amazon-ec2, tin-can-api, learning-locker

I installed Learning Locker using Community AMI on AWS and the system said that it successfully build and running and I can connect to my server using ssh, but when I access public DNS of my instance I always get error 404 not found, and my server running nginx, ubuntu 10.4

I do not have a technical support while I use a free AWS account

So, what should I do?

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct key? I've never had any issue SSHing into an AWS server

Comment: I use a correct key, and I jist accessing AWS using SSH for downloading the  credential key from Learning Locker Installation, not to change server configuration